# Is there a way to insert nodes in a single linked list in Alphabetical order?

Tags: c

Inserting nodes at the beginning , end or at specific location is self evident. However is it possible to insert nodes in alphabetical order in a linked list

Comment: search for the position where to insert - and then insert.

Comment: the answer is : yes ... if the node has a field of type char *. More seriously why do you think it is not possible / difficult ?

Comment: Inserting the first node is easy, just add it. Inserting the second node is almost as easy, is it "alphabetically" smaller or larger than the existing node? That decide whether to add it before or after the current node. The third node? A little bit harder, as you now really have to find a suitable node to insert it after (or before). But for the fourth node it becomes easy again as it's just the same as for the third node. And so on for all the rest of the nodes you want to add.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude — I think the second node is the only complex one: you have to decide whether to insert it before the current node or add it to the end of the list (which is also 'after current node' when you've searched the entire list).  The same applies to the third; either it goes before the current node (which might be the head node), or it's added to the end.  The 'insert at front' means you have to return the (new) head of list each time — probably.  Or pass a pointer to the pointer to the first node.

Comment: "_is it possible_" is an odd question.  Better to just ask "_how_" since of course it is possible.  It is not possible however to present C code illustrating exactly how _you_ could do it without your first providing your list code and node structure in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. You can use `int strcmp ( const char * str1, const char * str2 );` to find the right position to insert while traversing the list and then insert it there.